# Could not deduce (Bounded a1) arising from a use of 'minBound'

Tags: haskell, types

This is probably a stupid question, but why does this function

```
myTest :: (Bounded a) => a
myTest = minBound :: a
```

not typecheck?

This works

```
myTest' :: Int
myTest' = minBound :: Int
```

and they seem the same to me, except that one would have to type the former (e.g. myTest :: Int) in order for it to work.

The error I get is

```
• Could not deduce (Bounded a1) arising from a use of ‘minBound’
  from the context: Bounded a
    bound by the type signature for:
               myTest :: Bounded a => a
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must enable `ScopedTypeVariables` using `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`, which allows you to use type variables from the function signature inside the function itself. You will also need to change your example as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

myTest :: forall a. (Bounded a) => a
myTest = minBound :: a
```

The `forall` tells the compiler to scope the `a`. Definitions with no explicit `forall` with have the default (unscoped) behavior.

Otherwise, the `a` inside the function is a different `a` (changed to `a1` by the compiler) than the one in the main type signature. It can't deduce that `a1` is Bounded from only the context that some other type `a` is bounded.

The second example works because `Int` is not a type variable, it is a concrete type, which means that it refers to the same type regardless of what type variables are or are not in scope.

[Further Reading](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables)